# What's the class library in the .NET Framework

Tags: .net

I'm starting to read `MSDN .NET Framework 4.5` manual and I've one doubt about .NET class library defenition. `MSDN` said the following:

> The .NET Framework consists of the common language runtime and the
>   .NET Framework class library

So what is the `.NET Framework class library`? It is `CLR` just assemblies or some modules with `native` .NET Framework code? Where can I looking for some class from this library?

Answer (score 1):

they refer to [Base Class Library of .NET](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library&ei=8vYhU52-CY2Y1AXl1YCwCA&usg=AFQjCNHefagpRffz4XpuoIr8v8KQzpacIg&sig2=6TcbPo-4dbKoBplX0LdB8g)

> The Base Class Library (BCL) is a Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) standard library available to all CLI languages. CLI includes the BCL in order to encapsulate a large number of common functions, such as file reading and writing, graphic rendering, database interaction, and XML document manipulation, which makes the programmer's job easier. It is much larger in scope than standard libraries for most other languages, including C++, and is comparable in scope and coverage to the standard libraries of Java. The .NET Framework, being the first implementation of CLI, is the origin of the BCL. It is sometimes incorrectly referred to as the Framework Class Library (FCL), but the FCL is actually a superset including Microsoft specific namespaces.
>   The BCL is updated with each version of the .NET Framework.